# jQuery displaying a div when a hyperlink is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have trolled the internet and Stack Overflow to try and work out why how to hide this div:

```
<div id="blackandwhite">
```

But - this isn't as easy as it looks, I also have to display it when one of these hyperlinks is clicked, as these move into panels of jQuery:

```
<div class="stevenav">
<ul class="navigation">
<li><a href="#firstpagename"><?php echo the_field('first_page_name'); ?></a></li>
<li><a href="#secondpagename"><?php echo the_field('second_page_name'); ?></a></li>
<li><a href="#thirdpagename"><?php echo the_field('third_page_name'); ?></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I seriously cannot get it to work, Also I would appreciate if you looked at the site as there are and might be some conflicting JS as there is currently a lot on there at the moment. (ready to be a little neater once it is finished.

Comment: To hide a div using jquery you would write $("#blackandwhite").hide();

But i have no idea what your asking in the second part of your question

Comment: Hello Sam Warren! Sorry - what I mean't to say is I think there is conflicting javascript on this site but I cannot seem to work out what is making the JQuery that people supply to not work?

the link is: steveatattooartist.com

Comment: using firebug i get an error saying that it can not find jQuery. The error message says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for your JQuery file. I would double check  that the link to your jquery is correct

Comment: Cheers Sam! I'll have a look - I did overload the site with far too many link's and I am now stripping it down to ensure the code is clean and better.

I am comfortable around other coding language's JavaScript just completely confuses me but I have definitely learned quick.. so Thank you!

Comment: No problem :) If you still cant sort the issue ill check any messages you leave on here :) Good luck!

Comment: Sam, I have actually re-posted another question explaining the detail's better of what I wish the jQuery to do and I believe I am close to getting where I am with the site. If you get the chance to have a look then it is available here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/q/9474148/1233905

Otherwise, do not worry and thank you for all your help so far! It's been more than helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply write it like this,

```
$('#blackandwhite').hide();
$('li>a').click(function() {
    $('#blackandwhite').show();
});
```

Also, if you would like to toggle show/hide, you can use the toggle effect. By just replacing the show() with toggle()

```
$('#blackandwhite').toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is hard about it, maybe I am missing the point

```
jQuery(function() {
    var blackWhite = jQuery("#blackandwhite").hide();
    jQuery("#firstpagename, #secondpagename, #thirdpagename").on("click", function() {
        blackWhite.show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var elm = $("#blackandwhite");
elm.hide();
$(".navigation li a").on('click', function() {
    elm.show();
});
```