# Toggling the Div's on and off through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Stackoverflowers!

Over the last few post's you have all helped me get extremely far and I am now facing another problem if you are able to help me, I also think that the last times I have not explained very well, so here it goes.

I have 3 id divs, named: white, v2black, v3black. My aim is to have a hyperlink nav that toggles each one of the Div's on and Off; however, when one is clicked, it must hide the current active div so two are not visible at the same time.

Just incase, the link for the source and the live site is: www.steveatattooartist.com

I have tried enough and this is where I am at the moment:

My jQuery:

```
<script>
 jQuery(function() {
  $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-for');
    $('#' + id).toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

My Html Structure:

```
<div class="altstevenav" style="display:none">
<div class="stevenav">
<ul class="navigation">
<li><a href="#firstpagename" id="firstpagename"><?php echo the_field('first_page_name'); ?></a></li>
<li><a href="#secondpagename" id="secondpagename"><?php echo the_field('second_page_name'); ?></a></li>
<li><a href="#thirdpagename" id="thirdpagename"><?php echo the_field('third_page_name'); ?></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

</div> <!--MAIN CLOSING DIV-->
</div> <!--CONTENT CLOSING DIV-->

<div class="delstevenav">
<div class="stevenav">
<ul class="navigation">
<li><a href="#firstpagename" id="firstpagename"><?php echo the_field('first_page_name'); ?></a></li>
<li><a href="#secondpagename" id="secondpagename"><?php echo the_field('second_page_name'); ?></a></li>
<li><a href="#thirdpagename" id="thirdpagename"><?php echo the_field('third_page_name'); ?></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<!--ALL DIVS ARE CLOSE HERE-->

<!--Divisional Panels-->
<div id="white  class="toggle" data-for="white">
<div style="width:968px; margin: 0 auto;">
<div class="panel" style="color:#000000;">
<div style="width:450px; float:left;">
<img src="<?php echo the_field('image_one_of_biography'); ?>" width="425" alt="Biography Image" />
<br /><br />
<img src="<?php echo the_field('image_two_of_biography'); ?>" width="425" alt="Biography Image" />
<br /><br />
<img src="<?php echo the_field('image_three_of_biography'); ?>" width="425" alt="Biography Image" />
</div>
<div style="width:450px; float:left; text-align:left;">
<?php echo the_field('biography_content'); ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="v2black" class="toggle" data-for="v2black">
<div style="width:968px; height:500px; margin: 0 auto;">

</div>
</div>

<div id="v3black"  class="toggle" data-for="v3black">
<div style="width:968px; height:500px; margin: 0 auto;">

</div></div>

</div>
```

Really hope someone could help me because you guys have seriously helped me get really far in this project and I appreciate it, A LOT!

Comment: On the referenced page you have a markup issue: `<div id="white class=" data-for="white" toggle?="">` perhaps should be: `<div id="white"  class="toggle" data-for="white">`

Answer (score 2):

Your div's need to have a common attribute (e.g. class), so you can hide them all first, and then show the active div. The `toggle` class is common to all of them, so:

```
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    $(".toggle").hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-for');
    $('#' + id).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

Using the console in my browser, I changed the links to look like this:

```
<div class="altstevenav" style="display: none; ">
    <div class="stevenav">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li>
                <a href="#firstpagename" id="firstpagename" data-for="white">Steve A</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#secondpagename" id="secondpagename" data-for="v2black">Tattoos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#thirdpagename" id="thirdpagename" data-for="v3black">Sketchbook</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="stevenav">
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li>
            <a href="#firstpagename" id="firstpagename2" data-for="white">Steve A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#secondpagename" id="secondpagename2" data-for="v2black">Tattoos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#thirdpagename" id="thirdpagename2" data-for="v3black">Sketchbook</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then I re-assigned the click handlers thusly:

```
$('ul.navigation a[data-for]').click(function (e) {
    var targetDiv = $(this).attr('data-for');
    $('div.common').hide();
    $('div#' + targetDiv).show();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

You will probably also want to do:

```
$('div.common').hide();
$('div#white').show();
```

somewhere in `$(document).ready()` to have only the `white` div showing initially.

This seemed to have the desired effect. Try these changes and let us know if that worked for you.

**-- previous answer below --**

A couple of suggestions:

1. The line `<div id="white  class="toggle" data-for="white">` should probably be `<div id="white"  class="toggle" data-for="white">` instead.
2. The only real difference between `div.altstevenav` and `div.delstevenav` is the containing element. You should either give the links in one different `id` attributes or consider not using `id` attributes at all.
3. The `v2black` and `v3black` divs are both children of the `white` div. You should make them siblings of the `white` div, either by moving them out of the `white` div, or by using the current div (with `id="white"`) as a container div (with no `id` attribute) and making a new child div of the container with `id="white"` instead.
4. For the links that you want to use to trigger the div visibility-toggling action, you should move the `data-for` attributes to the those links instead of on the target divs.

Example of links (Point 2):

```
<div class="altstevenav" style="display:none">
    <div class="stevenav">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li>
                <a href="#firstpagename" id="altfirstpagename">Steve A</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#secondpagename" id="altsecondpagename">Tattoos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#thirdpagename" id="altthirdpagename">Sketchbook</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--MAIN CLOSING DIV-->
</div>
<!--CONTENT CLOSING DIV-->
<div class="delstevenav">
    <div class="stevenav">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li>
                <a href="#firstpagename" id="delfirstpagename">Steve A</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#secondpagename" id="delsecondpagename">Tattoos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#thirdpagename" id="delthirdpagename">Sketchbook</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

or

```
 <div class="altstevenav" style="display:none">
    <div class="stevenav">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li>
                <a href="#firstpagename">Steve A</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#secondpagename">Tattoos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#thirdpagename">Sketchbook</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--MAIN CLOSING DIV-->
</div>
<!--CONTENT CLOSING DIV-->
<div class="delstevenav">
    <div class="stevenav">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li>
                <a href="#firstpagename">Steve A</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#secondpagename">Tattoos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#thirdpagename">Sketchbook</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can then use the follwing jQuery to get the job done (Point 4):

```
$('a[data-for]').click(function (e) {
    var targetDiv = $(this).attr('data-for');
    $('div.toggle').hide();
    $(targetDiv).show();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Hey Pete! I hope your about - Thank you for your feedback, I have applied what you've said above and it still has not effected or made a difference in my work. no div's are set to hide as default, they are all showing constantly and are not linking? - any ideas? Would love it if you could help...

Comment: Ok, updated answer. Try it out. Also, I noticed you renamed the `toggle` class `common`. Although it shouldn't hurt anything, it was probably unnecessary. I'm just wondering why the change. :)

Comment: Hey did eventually work it out, I don't know why but that code just wasn't working? :/ probably me, but I posted another post and done it in a different way! I had to assign different I'd tags to do the two changing navs. Eventually it was sorted after days of doing jQuery for the first time. Would just like to say thank you very much for your help! Never touched jQuery before and actually know what to look for now and slightly understand some basics :) cheers pal!

Answer (score 0):

toggle to hide not current ones:

```
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    $(".toggle").not('#' + $(this).data('for')).hide();
});
```